# Given matrix $A$ and $B$, if matrix $B$ is not invertible what is matrix $C$ if $BC = A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Find matrix $C$ if: $$ A = \begin{bmatrix}1&3&2\\-1&2&1\\0&1&0 \end{bmatrix} \space  B = \begin{bmatrix}3&2&1\\1&1&1\\1&2&3 \end{bmatrix}, \space BC = A $$

I started off this question by attempting to find the inverse of $B$, but then I discovered that $B$ is not invertible. Is it still possible to isolate for $C$ and solve or is this answer no solution?

Comment: You can't say there's no solution just because B isn't invertible.  Pick some random matrix $C$ and compute $BC$.  Now you can call the answer $A$ and challenge your friends to find $C$.

Comment: In this case, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -4 & 1 \end{bmatrix} B = 0$ but $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -4 & 1 \end{bmatrix} A \ne 0$ which makes it impossible for a solution to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the equation $B\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ has a solution iff $\mathbf b$ is an element of the column space of $B$, the equation $BC=A$ can be solved iff every column of $A$ is in the column space of $B$. So augment $B$ with $A$ and row-reduce: $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc} 3&2&1 & 1&2&3 \\ 1&1&1 & -1&2&1 \\ 1&2&3 & 0&1&0 \end{array}\right] \to \left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc} 1&0&-1 & -2&3&2 \\ 0&1&2 & 1&-1&-1 \\ 0&0&0 & 5&-5&1 \end{array}\right].$$ *No* column of $A$ is in $B$’s column space, so there’s no solution. Perhaps there’s an error in the problem or you’ve misread it.

Comment: Nope, the question is written as is. Your answer was clear and concise, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**The answer is no, twice.**
If $B$ is singular, it is a zero divisor. Your equation does not have a unique solution.

However, this doesn't matter since your equation has no solutions at all. $B$ is singular, so $BC$ must be as well. This tells us $A$ is singular. However, $A$ is definitely invertible. This is a contradiction, so no solutions exist.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.
Find a row vector $\vec v$ for which $\vec vB=\vec0$.
Then $\vec vBC=\vec0C=\vec0$.
If $\vec vA\ne\vec0$ then there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes let $c$ be the first column of $C$, and $a$ the first column of $A$, then solve the system

$$Bc=a.$$ do the same doe the other columns. Simplify the work by writing $B,A$ and do row reduction on $B$.